# Python equivalent of the JavaScript bitwise >>>

Tags: javascript, python, bitwise-operators

Is there an equivalent of `>>>` operator of JavaScript in Python. As per `>>>` definition of JavaScript, the operator,

> Shifts right by pushing zeros in from the left, and let the rightmost bits fall off

So is there any direct operator in python as `>>` cannot do so in my opinion

Comment: `128 >> 6` yields `2` as expected. What more do you want? `>>>` is only different in JavaScript for [negative numbers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators#Unsigned_right_shift) which you shouldn't be bit-shifting in the first place.

Comment: Documentation for bitwise operations in Python is [here](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BitwiseOperators).

Comment: The difference in JS between `>>` and `>>>` has to do with how they handle the sign bit of negative numbers. But Python integers are infinite length, there's no sign bit.

Comment: @tadman thanks. I should have noticed that bit shifting negative numbers should'nt be my use case

Comment: thanks guys for solving this one quickly

Comment: Then the difference between `>>` and `>>>` doesn't even apply in JavaScript. In Python it works as expected *on positive numbers*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x << y`
Returns x with the bits shifted to the left by y places (and new bits on the right-hand-side are zeros). This is the same as multiplying `x` by `2**y`.

`x >> y`
Returns x with the bits shifted to the right by y places. This is the same as integer-dividing `x` by `2**y`.

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is not applying bit shifts to negative numbers and that was the only difference between `>>>` and `>>`